# Spring JPA @Query where clause with 'like' and 'or'

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, sql-like

I have the following query:

```
@Query("select c from Category c where ( (lower(c.name) like '%' || lower(:searchText) || '%') or (lower(c.description) like '%' || lower(:searchText)) || '%')")
```

My product is designed to run in multiple platform, I am getting an error on postgreSQL which is:

> PSQLException: ERROR: argument of OR must be type boolean, not type
>   text.

Which is undestandable since the like clause return strings. But I wasn't able to perform the search in one query request. So the question is how can I perform a search where the where conditions refer to 2 differnt columns and use the 'like' operator.

Comment: Try adding explicit parentheses to group operations. I think you're having operator precedence issues.

Comment: You mean to add parentheses around the comparison paramenter?, if so, i didn't work

Comment: can you *show me* what you tried (Where you added the parens) and exactly it "didn't work"? Please include your PostgreSQL version and the real underlying SQL that EclipesLink/Hibernate/whatever turned that HQL into. You can get that from the PostgreSQL logs with `log_statement = 'all'` or from your ORM's logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses you have are not correct the following should work:

```
@Query("select c from Category c " +
       "where (lower(c.name) like ('%' || lower(:searchText) || '%')) " +
         " or (lower(c.description) like ('%' || lower(:searchText) || '%'))")
```